# Ignore Changes to a file in Github among all forks, without deleting the file from repository

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitignore

There is a config/auth.js file in my github repository (which has many forks) I want to ignore any further changes to this file. After searching I found the following three ways but none of them is working for me :
1. **git rm --chaced** 
this deletes the file.
2. **git update-index --assume-unchanged config/auth.js**
this is working on my machine but then every contributor will have to run this command on his fork as well(which i do not want them to do).
3. **git update-index --skip-worktree config/auth.js**
same problem as case 2
Basically i dont want others to know anything happened and when the sync their fork(rebase) the changes in the file are ignored autmatically.

Comment: The direct answer is NO. Files managed by github only for which are version controlled by git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solution to do what you're asking is going to have a *ton* of "behind the scene's magic" that could go very wrong at any time; I don't recommend it.

The problem is that if you want to ignore their change to a given file, but you don't want them to see any effects of what you've done, then you necessarily need to be looking at a different set of commits than they are.  For example, if you have

```
x --- x --- x <--(master)
```

and they clone, so they have

```
x --- x --- x <--(origin/master)(master)
```

and then they make some changes, including an edit to the config, so they have

```
x --- x --- x <--(origin/master)
             \
              O <--(master)
```

for your repo to "ignore" the change to the config file means that you'll end up with

```
x --- x --- x --- O' <--(master)
```

after incorporating their changes.  `O'` is *necessarily* a distinct commit from `O`.  The client will expect to see `O` at `origin/master` and indeed it would be very disruptive if you presented them with the "reality" that `origin/master` is now at `O'`.

So to keep things working neatly, you have to store `O` and represent to the fork that the upstream of `master` points to `O`.  Given that you have more than one fork, each of which might have its own changes to your config file, you have to either:

1) Create a "bridge" repo for each fork, and thereby change the remote URL they use to address you,

or

2) Maintain in your origin repo a separate set of branches for each fork, requiring the forks to configure an appropriate refspec.

So truly making this change "invisible" just isn't possible.  Assuming you want the "lighter weight" of those two options - which I believe would be (2) - you would end up with something like

```
x --- x --- x --- O <--(master)
             \
              O' <--(fork-a/master)
```

and now you'd have to use hooks to automate rebasing of changes between `master` and `fork-a/master` (while filtering changes to the config file out of the rebases).  I see nothing but opportunities for disaster there.

The other option (bridge repos) still looks pretty much like the above.  It just keeps things from looking *even worse* in any single repo, given that you actually have many forks. It structures how changes flow between forks I guess, but then you have to coordinate between all those repos.

I can't see either of those really working.

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm --cached
```

This will un-stage a file *from the index*. It has no lasting effect on a repository.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged config/auth.js
git update-index --skip-worktree config/auth.js
```

As you have stated, these work on your local index, but are not shared (just like the first option).

I think all you need to do is add the path to `.gitignore` in the repository, and commit `.gitignore`.

Since `.gitignore` just tells Git to ignore the path when doing add/commit, any changes people might make to their local copy will be ignored during add/commit, and the same goes for your copy. So no changes should be introduced to the file.

At the same time, `.gitignore` is not a magic wand to erase the file's existing history. So its current state should stay there and it will remain in your history and git-log. You just won't be able to alter it anymore (unless it's removed from `.gitignore`).